# RemoteCertificateNameMismatch when sending SMTP email

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, smtp, certificate

I'm trying to send an email using Outlook in our company with EnableSSL=True. However, I can't solve the issue I'm encountering at the moment with my sample code below:

```
public static bool RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
    }

    public static void SendMail()
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback;
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.abccompany.com"))
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("john.smith@abccompany.com");
                mail.To.Add("john.smith@abccompany.com");
                mail.Subject = "Test";
                mail.Body = "Test!";

                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

                smtp.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The value of SslPolicyErrors is "RemoteCertificateNameMismatch" and I don't have a clue how to fix it. I tried to export the certificate value from the "RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback" method to a file and install it in my machine and still the issue is not fix. Any idea pls...

Comment: Is `mail.abccompany.com` in CN or SubjectAlternativeName of the certificate you exported from `RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback`? You need to choose one of them to fix this error. And the certificate needs to be trusted of course (chain built to trusted root, CRLs available etc.)

Comment: Hi pepo! thanks for the reply. mail.abccompany.com is not in the SubjectAlternativeName of the certificate. I don't know what CN means but I'm guessing it is the certificate name? I can't find mail.abccompany.com in any of the certificate properties.

Comment: So there is your problem. CN is common name in Subject of the certificate. Either use value in CN or pick one of the DNS names from SubjectAlternativeName field and it should work fine.

Comment: See a solution available at: https://www.limilabs.com/blog/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure for smooth handling of exception you are getting.

Comment: Hello again Pepo! Thank you so much for your help. Because of your answer I was able to understand my problem and eventually solved it. How can I mark your answer as the solution?